# Algorithm for connecting points in different layers through nodes without intersection

Tags: algorithm

I have two set of points, {A1, B1, C1, D1, E1} and {A2, B2, C2, D2, E2}. A1 connects to A2, B1 connects to B2, etc. The first set of points locates at layer 1 and the second set of points locates at layer 2. Thus, I need to connect every pair of points through layer-switching nodes.

For example:
[Image_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEn7Z.png)

My problem is that I don’t know where to put those nodes to make sure there is no intersection in each layer.

.

What I’ve tried:

I generate some grids as potential coordinates for nodes between two sets of points([Image_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YmOp.png)). However, there are two problems:

1. When the order of points changes, the number of grids  I need could be vary. For example, less than 5x5 grids in [Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKO1v.png) and 7x5 grids in [Image_4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzlCx.png).
2. I am using a brute-force method currently to connect nodes and points, but it spends a tremendous amount of time when the number of points increases. Obviously, I need a more efficient way.

Is there any algorithm that helps? Do those grids help?

Comment: Are you trying to build a disjoint set?

Comment: @Neil Yes, it's a disjoint set. Every connection contains two points, two lines, and a node. Every line or node is used only in one single connection.

Comment: What do you mean, "no intersection in each layer?" Maybe [Prim's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm) or [Kruskal's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) with equal weighted edges?

Comment: @Neil Blue lines are in layer 1, Red lines are in layer 2, and nodes are in both layers. Lines in the same layer do not cross each other or intersect with the nodes they aren't supposed to connect.
Thanks for your advice. I will try the two algorithms.

Comment: And you need a MST for each layer? As long as the layers are orthogonal, I think you can do that with Kruskal's, just treat every layer independently.